# How to bring feature selection into Printing Composer?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-2.2

I'd like to make maps of Finland's municipalities. Our National Land Survey provides data I can make into a Shapefile, and when a municipality is selected in QGIS/Identify Features, three different levels of associated administrative boundaries are helpfully highlighted, even the exclaves and enclaves of the selected municipality.

My question then is, how can I export this exact map view? When I open a new Print Composer, the selection/color scheme is gone. The exclaves are an important feature I'd like to keep.

[image: finnish municipalities]

You can probably see that there are hundreds of those tiny exclaves, whose names aren't easily readable in the GML, so I really wouldn't bother checking up manually which of them belong where, and then color them in Inkscape.

I tried exporting with the plugin SimpleSVG, but it just compresses the shapes into uglyness. Compare original and after:

[image]

Comment: If the maps are to be used with limited resolution - try to save the view from QGis as image, rather then going by print composer. Selections are exported in the images just like they show on screen

Comment: @TimCouwelier Unfortunately, it is vectors that I desire.

Comment: We also have this problem. In QGIS 2.0 and earlier, this worked perfectly: with QGIS 2.4, all features are unselected in the print composer.

Comment: Can you reproduce it with QGis 2.4 and 2.6 ? I can't and I need it for my users.

Answer (score 2):

Late answer but you can keep the features highlighted and see them in Print Composer...just not by using *Identify Features* (atleast not in QGIS 2.2). You have to select the features either manually or with a filter:

[image: Selected features]

You can then see the highlighted features in your composer:

[image: Print Composer]

Lastly, you can then save it as an image or in this case as an .svg (bear in mind that the lines come out as chunky vectors):

[image: Saved as .svg]

Comment: Thank you! I will look into this. I'll also try out QGIS 2.0 or an earlier version.

Comment: Most welcome buddy, hope you get the results you want!