# Synchronizing QGIS Print Composer with map view?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, print-composer

I want to create a template using the "Print Composer" from my layers loaded in QGIS 2.18.7 (Las Palmas). The problem is that it seems the map element is not "synchronized" with the map view. For instance, if I zoom-in on the map view, I want the map element on the template also being automatically updated with the zoom.

Another problem related to this is that I don't know how to display the selected features in the template: 
[image]

Is there any way of updating the map template automatically?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? There's at least a button for updating the map window in the print composer. Select the map item -> properties -> extent -> Set to map canvas extent

Comment: In terms of showing selected features in the print composer, this was asked before: [How to bring feature selection into Printing Composer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95498/how-to-bring-feature-selection-into-printing-composer). However, it seems that in the recent versions of QGIS, it no longer seems possible unless you perform a query...

Comment: Thanks @Joseph I've already read the question you linked. With the query I can zoom-in to the selected features but what I want to achieve is to highlight them as in the map view.

Comment: @Nightwatch  know it but I need it to be updated automatically, anyway with the function you have told me do not select anything in the print composer

Comment: @ustadra - The only workaround I can think of at the moment is to style your layer with something like **Rule-based**. You could create an attribute field in your layer and only update the _selected features_ with a specific value. Then give one colour to all features and another colour to features with the specific value.

Comment: @Joseph Following your advice I have managed to see the selected item but without adding a new field, I have put it in response to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally used this solution:

In layer Properties->Style->Rule-based
[image]

With $id=$atlasfeatureid I can see the items selected by the atlas

[image]

Answer (score 8):

With a little help from **Python**, we could create a function which refreshes your composer map each time the canvas extent (from the main window) has changed. In otherwords, whenever you pan or zoom in/out of the canvas, the composer map will also update. You can type the following code into the **Python Console**:

```
def update_composer():
    active_Composer = iface.activeComposers()
    canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
    composer = active_Composer[0]
    composition = composer.composition()
    maps = [item for item in composition.items() if item.type() == QgsComposerItem.ComposerMap and item.scene()]
    composer_map = maps[0]
    moveX = composer_map.extent().center().x()-canvas.extent().center().x()
    moveY = composer_map.extent().center().y()-canvas.extent().center().y()
    unitCon = composer_map.mapUnitsToMM()
    composer_map.moveContent(-moveX * unitCon, moveY * unitCon)
    composer_map.setNewScale(canvas.scale())

iface.mapCanvas().extentsChanged.connect(update_composer)
```

---

*Credit to the author Ed B for his plugin: [Sync Composer With Map](https://github.com/boesiii/synccomposerwithmap) of which this code was based upon (you can download/install this plugin from the menubar:* `Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins...`).

Comment: @ustadra - Most welcome, glad it was helpful :)

Answer (score 4):

I try this solution:

```
def print_image(self):
    layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()
    """select layer by name"""
    for name, layer in layers.iteritems():
        if(layer.name()=="[YOUR LAYER NAME]"):

            lay=layer
    self.iface.mapCanvas().zoomToSelected( lay )
    self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
    path = 'C:\new folder\image.png'
    self.iface.mapCanvas().saveAsImage(path)
```

This makes a photo of the map view and I get the selected objects

Answer (score 0):

In the "Layers" section you just need to thick the "Follow map theme" option and your current view from QGIS should have to come out.

[image]